# deselecting checkbox is removing whole row from the front-end angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox

i have this Panel array coming from backend which has another array Tests. i have mapped them on my custom accordion with checkboxes. the problem i am facing is i should be able to select/deselect Tests without removing it from the from front-end like it Disappears when i deselect. how can i solve this issue?

you can see from that image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJUFy.png

**here is my html file**

```
<ngb-panel *ngFor="let panel of panels" id="{{panel.Id}}" [title]="panel.Name">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [name]="panel.Id + '-' + panel.Moniker" [ngModel]="checkAllTestsSelected(panel)" (ngModelChange)="onPanelCheckboxUpdate($event, panel)" [id]="panel.Id + '-' + panel.Moniker">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    </label>

    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
        <div class="individual-panel" *ngFor="let test of panel.Tests">
            <span class="text-dimmed">{{test.Name}}</span>
            <span *ngIf="panel.Name.includes('ENA') || panel.Name.includes('Celiac')">
                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [name]="test.Id + '-' + test.Code"
                    [ngModel]="testSelectionSession.SelectedPanelIds.indexOf(panel.Id) > -1 || testSelectionSession.SelectedPanelIds.indexOf(test.AssociatedPanel?.Id) > -1"
                    (ngModelChange)="onTestCheckboxUpdate($event, test, panel)" 
                    [id]="test.Id + '-' + test.Code">
                    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                </label>
            </span>
        </div>
```

**ts file**

```
checkAllTestsSelected(panel: TestOrderPanel) {
    // get all individual test panels
    let individualTestPanelIds = panel.Tests.reduce((acc, test) => {
        if (test.AssociatedPanel) {
            acc.push(test.AssociatedPanel.Id);
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);

    // check if all individual test panels are selected

    let allIndividualTestsSelected = individualTestPanelIds.reduce(
        (acc: boolean, panelId: number) =>
        acc && this.panelIds.indexOf(panelId) > -1,
        individualTestPanelIds.length > 0 &&
        panel.Tests.length === individualTestPanelIds.length
    );

    // if selected, remove all individual test panels and add the panel group
    if (panel.Tests.length > 0 && allIndividualTestsSelected) {
        this.panelIds = this.panelIds.filter(
            panelId => individualTestPanelIds.indexOf(panelId) === -1
        );
        this.selectedPanels = this.selectedPanels.filter(
            selectedPanel => individualTestPanelIds.indexOf(selectedPanel.Id) === -1
        );
        this.panelIds.push(panel.Id);
        this.selectedPanels.push(panel);
        this.updateSession();
    }
    return this.panelIds.indexOf(panel.Id) > -1;
}


onPanelCheckboxUpdate($event: boolean, panel: TestOrderPanel) {
    let testPanelIds = panel.Tests.reduce((acc, test) => {
        if (test.AssociatedPanel) {
            acc.push(test.AssociatedPanel.Id);
        }

        return acc;
    }, []);

    // Wipe any duplicates
    this.panelIds = this.panelIds.filter(
        panelId => panel.Id !== panelId && testPanelIds.indexOf(panelId) === -1
    );
    this.selectedPanels = this.selectedPanels.filter(
        selectedPanel =>
        panel.Id !== selectedPanel.Id &&
        testPanelIds.indexOf(selectedPanel.Id) === -1
    );

    if ($event) {
        this.panelIds.push(panel.Id);
        this.selectedPanels.push(panel);
    }
    this.updateSession();
}

onTestCheckboxUpdate($event: boolean,
    test: TestOrderPanelTest,
    panel: TestOrderPanel,
    index) {

    let testPanelIds = panel.Tests.reduce((acc, test) => {
        if (test.AssociatedPanel) {
            acc.push(test.AssociatedPanel.Id);
        }

        return acc;
    }, []);
    let associatedTestPanels =
        this.testSelectionSession.IndividualTestPanelsForAll.filter(
            testPanel => testPanelIds.indexOf(testPanel.Id) > -1
        );
    // If the panel is selected and a test within the panel is deselected,
    // remove the panel and back all of the individual tests
    if (this.panelIds.indexOf(panel.Id) > -1 && !$event) {
        this.selectedPanels = this.selectedPanels.filter(
            e => e.Tests.splice(index, 1)
        );
    }

    let clickedTestPanel = associatedTestPanels.find(
        testPanel => (test.AssociatedPanel ? test.AssociatedPanel.Id : -1) ===
        testPanel.Id
    );

    if (clickedTestPanel) {
        // Wipe any duplicates
        this.panelIds = this.panelIds.filter(
            panelId => clickedTestPanel.Id !== panelId
        );
        this.selectedPanels = this.selectedPanels.filter(
            panel => clickedTestPanel.Id !== panel.Id
        );

        // Add individual panel if checkbox selected
        if ($event) {
            this.panelIds = this.panelIds.concat(clickedTestPanel.Id);
            this.selectedPanels = this.selectedPanels.concat(clickedTestPanel);
        }
    }
    this.updateSession();
}
```

this.panelIds includes IDs of panels and this.selectedPanels includes whole panel array which is selected.

i have created a stackblitz too

my code is doing something like that stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bsszc9

and here is example of how my page will look like
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvbwtr)

how can i solve this problem?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Delete

```
if (this.panelIds.indexOf(panel.Id) > -1 && !$event) {
    this.selectedPanels = this.selectedPanels.filter(
        e => e.Tests.splice(index, 1)
    );
}
```

This part doesn't do anything but removing checkboxes and panels for no logical reason in a very random way (removing the checkbox with the same index from each panel and if there isn't any remove the whole panel)

Please read: [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to understand how is this happening.

Comment: how to solve this issue then if i remove this block

Comment: The issue is caused by this block, removing it will solve the issue!

Comment: i did that. i want to deselect the individual test so that it will be removed from array.
this code of mine is removing the whole row from front-end